# (1234)%6 = ((123%6)*10 + 4)%6 why this relation works?

Tags: number-theory, modular-arithmetic

I know these relations,   **(a * b * c * d...)%m = ((a%m) * (b%m) * (c%m) * (d%m)......)
%m**

and   ***(a+b+c+d+........)%m = (a%m + b%m + c%m + d%m)%m***

But , how does this relation work?

1297 % 6 = ((129%6)*10 + 7)%6

129 % 6 = ((12%6)*10 + 9 ) %6

and so on .....

If I expand 129 % 6

```
                  = (12*10 + 9) % 6

                  = (12*10 % 6 + 9%6)%6

                  = ????
```

How to proceed from here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general:

> $(10k+m)\%d = ((k\%d)*10+m)\%d$ for any integers $k,m,d$.

Your question is just a special case where $d = 6$.

The identity follows because $k = ad+k\%d$ for some integer $a$, and hence $(10k+m)\%d = (10(ad+k\%d)+m)\%d$

$ = (10ad+10(k\%d)+m)\%d$

$ = (10(k\%d)+m)\%d$.

Comment: Then can I extend this idea?For any X , (X*k + m)%d = ((k%d)*X + m)%d right?

Comment: @ZAN: Of course. I forgot to replace "$10$" by a new symbol; too used to thinking in base $10$. =)